# Not getting line number of exception in dot net app

Tags: .net

I have got a data migration app writting in .Net 3.0 VS2008.

I have deployed in debug mode and copied the PDB
file to the server I want to runit.

I get an exception but no line number.

This is how i display the exception

Why is there no line number of the exception???

Malcolm

```
       string msg = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",ex.Message,ex.StackTrace.ToString(),ex.Source.ToString());               
        if(ex.InnerException != null)
            msg += string.Format(" {0}", ex.InnerException.ToString());
        return msg;
```

Answer (score 10):

If you aren't getting line numbers, then either

**a)** The .NET runtime is determining that the .pdb doesn't match the assembly (out of date, compiled with optimizations, etc.)

or

**b)** The assembly is running from a directory that's different from the one containing the .pdb (a Windows service, for example, runs under %WINDOWS%\System32)

It doesn't sound like the first possibility applies to you, so is this a Windows service or is the execution directory being changed?

In any event, you should be able to use the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` property to determine where assemblies and .pdb's would be searched for (by the default, this can be overridden but should be a good indicator if it's being changed)

Comment: Great answer! I think you covered all the possibilities. +1

Comment: Thx. Could there be a **c)** in your answer? In my case I'm not getting a line number, but the only exception I'm causing is a `System.Web.HttpException` (trying to go to a page that does not exist). I'm not getting a line number with Exception, or if I do try to force one, it always returns '0'. Could this be why? AKA, the reason I'm not getting a line number is because there's nothing wrong with any of my code lines - I simply tried to visit to a non existent route. (?). Or should I still be getting line numbers w/ `System.Web.HTTPException`?

Answer (score 1):

dont mess with the exception string... trying to pretty it up, just ex.toString() on it to get the stack to unwind and print the info you are looking for

Of course the pdb files need to be there for the debug info. but formatting the exception is completely unnecessary just call ex.toString() and it formats it for you.